# Unable to store nepali date in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store form values in database. But i'm able to store all
 the form values except nepali date. My code is given below. I'm able to insert English date when i used input type as date and insert date from the English calendar.

registration.php

```
<div class="form-group ">
  <label>दर्ता मिति</label>
  <input type="text" name="registration_date" autocomplete="off" class="form-control date-picker " value="<?php echo $registration_date; ?>">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(".date-picker").nepaliDatePicker({
     dateFormat: "%y-%m-%d",
     closeOnDateSelect: true

   }); 
 </script>
</div>

<?php
require_once "conn.php";
$registration_date = $fiscalyear_id = $houseowner_name_np = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $registration_date  = trim($_POST["registration_date"]);
    $fiscalyear_id      = trim($_POST["fiscalyear_id"]);
    $houseowner_name_np = trim($_POST["houseowner_name_np"]);
    $sql                = "INSERT INTO bps_registration_newregistration (registration_date, fiscalyear_id, houseowner_name_np) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $registration_date, $fiscalyear_id, $houseowner_name_np);
        $registration_date  = $registration_date;
        $fiscalyear_id      = $fiscalyear_id;
        $houseowner_name_np = $houseowner_name_np;
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: what is your column's data type?

Comment: What do you mean `Nepali format`?  You should only send `YYYY-MM-DD` to the database - always. Then format it as you want on output. But any date-column will *always* be stored in that format, so you should send it in that format.

Comment: _Side note:_ What's the point of the `$registration_date  = $registration_date;`? Setting a variable to itself seems a bit... pointless?

Comment: My column data type in database is date type. @Amit Rajput

Comment: I put trim($_POST["registration_date"]) in $registration_date. @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: First you do that, but then, after your bind, you also do `$registration_date = $registration_date;` (and the same for the other two variables) which is completely pointless since you're just setting that variable to the value it already has.

Comment: Can I insert unicode i.e selected from the nepali calender in database or I have to convert it in english date? @Qirel

Comment: I tried by changing variable name too. But its not working.@Magnus Eriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DATE` type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATE` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`.

There are two ways to solve your problem.

1. You can change date format and then save into database table.
2. Or change the column's data type `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`

The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, `CHAR(30)` can hold up to 30 characters.

Hope it will help.

Comment: "*Or change the column's data type CHAR or VARCHAR*" that's a very bad idea. Use date-type columns instead, so you can use the native date functions in SQL.

Comment: Store the date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' Format and while fetching the date render it to which ever format you want to though it may be of any country specific date.Dont change the format in database as if you are storing date in your database then it should be always of date type or datetime format so it would be easy to fetch the data or compare the date while doing sql query.

Comment: Yes @Qirel definitely you are right. I know the first one is best and standard way to store date in MYSQL. But if there are no any operations to be performed like extract month/year or add/subtract days etc and just need to store date for display purpose and exact format like nepali format then I think we can go for it that's why the second one is an alternate way to do so.

Comment: No, I highly disagree with it. Always - and I mean always - store data in their proper data-type. So for dates, use date-types and never any string values! Alter the format on output if needed, but store it properly.

Comment: Ok. I will do it

Comment: Can I ask other php question? @Qirel

Comment: Of course, but you might be better off actually posting a new question :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `nepaliDatepicker` function will show the date in string format, so it is better to change the column type to varchar for the Nepali date, with max length of 10 characters.